# How to remove previously selected options in PHP form with multiple select dropdowns

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am creating a game launch form with four dropdown selection boxes.  Each box will be used to select a player (players are pulled from the user's friend's list in my mysql database).  I am using PHP to dynamically populate the list of options (potential players).

Each of the  items have a unique name and id.

Is there a way to remove options that have already been selected from the other dropdowns?  I can find examples in javascript on here, but I haven't found one in PHP.

I've inserted the form code I'm using.  $option is just an array of usernames.  (Note: my if statement was a complete guess.  I'm not a seasoned coder by any means.)

```html
<form method="POST" action="game.php">
         <select id="1stPlayer" name="1stPlayer" required>
             <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select Player 1 (Team 1)</option>
                <?php

                $first = $_GET["1stPlayer"];
                $second = $_GET["2ndPlayer"];
                $third = $_GET["3rdPlayer"];
                $fourth = $_GET["4thPlayer"];

                echo implode(",",array_unique($option));

                 foreach ($option as $row) {
                   $value = $row;
                     if ($value != $second && $value != $third && $value != $fourth ) {
                       echo '<option value="'. $value .'">'. $value .'</option>';
                       };
                     };
             ?>
           </select>
           <select id="2ndPlayer" name="2ndPlayer" required>
               <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select Player 1 (Team 1)</option>
                  <?php

                  $first = $_GET["1stPlayer"];
                  $second = $_GET["2ndPlayer"];
                  $third = $_GET["3rdPlayer"];
                  $fourth = $_GET["4thPlayer"];

                  echo implode(",",array_unique($option));

                   foreach ($option as $row) {
                     $value = $row;
                       if ($value != $first && $value != $third && $value != $fourth ) {
                         echo '<option value="'. $value .'">'. $value .'</option>';
                         };
                       };
               ?>
             </select>
             <select id="$third" name="$third" required>
                 <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select Player 1 (Team 1)</option>
                    <?php

                    $first = $_GET["1stPlayer"];
                    $second = $_GET["2ndPlayer"];
                    $third = $_GET["3rdPlayer"];
                    $fourth = $_GET["4thPlayer"];

                    echo implode(",",array_unique($option));

                     foreach ($option as $row) {
                       $value = $row;
                         if ($value != $second && $value != $first && $value != $fourth ) {
                           echo '<option value="'. $value .'">'. $value .'</option>';
                           };
                         };
                 ?>
               </select>
               <select id="4thPlayer" name="4thPlayer" required>
                   <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select Player 1 (Team 1)</option>
                      <?php

                      $first = $_GET["1stPlayer"];
                      $second = $_GET["2ndPlayer"];
                      $third = $_GET["3rdPlayer"];
                      $fourth = $_GET["4thPlayer"];

                      echo implode(",",array_unique($option));

                       foreach ($option as $row) {
                         $value = $row;
                           if ($value != $second && $value != $third && $value != $first ) {
                             echo '<option value="'. $value .'">'. $value .'</option>';
                             };
                           };
                   ?>
                 </select>
              <input type="submit" name="startGame" id="single_game_button" value="Start Game">
            </form>
```

Comment: Change **and** to **or** in your if statement. ** if ($value != $first || $value != $third || $value != $fourth )**

Comment: removing the options using PHP makes no sense. PHP is what is used to create the dropdowns, so if you don't want something in a dropdown, then in your PHP, just don't add it in the first place

Comment: If you use **and** then it will look for the value in all the first, third and fourth according to your if statement, but if you use **or** then if any of the condition is true then your if options will run. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I updated the && to reflect an or statement and it still doesn't work.  I'm assuming the value doesn't get associated with the html element until the submit button is pressed.

Comment: ADyson, as I said, I'm not an expert so I don't know if it's possible to do what I'm asking while only using PHP.  But removing options is necessary for this application.  Player 1 and Player 2 can't be the same person.

Comment: Unless all the users are sat around the same monitor, the place to do this is the database.

Comment: If the page loads with all options in all select elements and you want an option to disappear from other selects when it is selected, then you have to use JS on the page to do that OR submit the page every time an option is changed so that the php on the server can recalculate the available options in each menu and rebuild the page. It is easier to use JS.

Comment: " I don't know if it's possible to do what I'm asking while only using PHP". Of course you could but why bother? So the first time your script runs, you populate the dropdowns. Then the user selects something...you postback the selection value to the server...your script runs again, but there is no HTML anymore, just the script. At this point _no dropdowns_, because your code hasn't created them yet. The previous page that was in the browser? It's gone, ceased to exist. The browser is waiting for PHP to generate a new one and send it. HTTP requests are _stateless_.

Comment: So yeah you could add the values, and then immediately, before you even send them to the browser, you'd have to remove them again based on the value the user sent you. So instead you'd simply write logic, based on the user input value, which would cause them not to be added to the HTML markup which you're in the middle of creating (_from scratch_, remember). That's what I meant by it being pointless to add them in the first place. Anyway, unless you need to persist this selection beyond the current instance of the page, it's much more efficient and user-friendly to do it using JavaScript.